# I'm having trouble debugging our implementation of Twitter's REST API v1.1

Tags: c#, twitter, utf-8, oauth, webclient

As part of the requirements of the project, OAuth was implemented from scratch without any pre-made libraries. The OAuth portion appears to be working correctly (we have checked numerous results of the signature against twitter's OAuth tool), but requests are failing with a `401 error` periodically.

With OAuth at least appearing to be returning a valid `Authorization` header, the only thing I can think of that could possibly be causing issues is the actual encoding and sending of the message once the header is generated.

This is where we send out the request:

```
private string Tweet(string tweetTxt)
{
    const string method = "POST";
    const string target = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json";

    NameValueCollection data = new NameValueCollection { { "status", tweetTxt } };
    NameValueCollection head = new NameValueCollection
                           {
                               {"user-agent", "AgentX"},
                               {"Authorization", oauth.GetHttpHeader(method, target, null, data)}
                           };
    // example OAuth header return value (wrapped for readability):
    // OAuth oauth_consumer_key="E6wtzO5DRloPq8Ba17osQ", 
    //       oauth_nonce="bfdc54f8b264e4d3d2595266b46d6118",
    //       oauth_signature="8%2B4vXDHYJ3jiWuDvGB6VBKwfWkg%3D", 
    //       oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
    //       oauth_timestamp="1390526341", 
    //       oauth_token="320761140-hJzRG2P9aVtySOS5wLphS4EADm7RfY6NRmZKbvA3", 
    //       oauth_version="1.0"
    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        client.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        client.Headers.Add(head);
        try
        {
            client.UploadValues(target, method, data);
            return @"Tweet Succeeded";
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return @"Tweet Failed";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there anything within that text that could cause issues? If not, is there anywhere else I should be looking? I can post additional detail if something specific is requested.

**EDIT:** I've concluded that the issue is in some related to certain characters. For example, if an `)` or `(` are in the tweet, it fails. That said, tweets with a hashtag, which has to be percent encoded, do not fail so it's not directly related to percent encoding. This all seems very odd given that both the Twitter OAuth tool and our program are generating the exact same `signature base string` and same `signature`.

**EDIT 2:** Since C# does not implement the RFC 3986 percent encoding, we implemented it ourselves. Don't particularly think it will end up being relevant, but, just in case, here it is:

```
private static string PercentEncode(string input)
{
    // List containing all byte values that don't need to be escaped.
    // Source: https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/percent-encoding-parameters
    byte[] nonEscaped =
    {
        // Digits
        0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37, 0x38, 0x39,

        // Uppercase Letters
        0x41, 0x42, 0x43, 0x44, 0x45, 0x46, 0x47, 0x48, 0x49, 0x4A, 0x4B, 0x4C, 0x4D,
        0x4E, 0x4F, 0x50, 0x51, 0x52, 0x53, 0x54, 0x55, 0x56, 0x57, 0x58, 0x59, 0x5A,

        // Lowercase Letters
        0x61, 0x62, 0x63, 0x64, 0x65, 0x66, 0x67, 0x68, 0x69, 0x6A, 0x6B, 0x6C, 0x6D,
        0x6E, 0x6F, 0x70, 0x71, 0x72, 0x73, 0x74, 0x75, 0x76, 0x77, 0x78, 0x79, 0x7A,

        // Reserved Characters
        0x2D, 0x2E, 0x5F, 0x7E
    };

    byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(input);
    List<byte> output = new List<byte>();

    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        if (nonEscaped.Contains(b))
        {
            output.Add(b);
        }
        else
        {
            // add percent char
            output.Add(0x25);

            // encode first and last half of byte
            int first = b & 0x0F;
            int last = b >> 4;
            output.Add(Convert.ToByte(last.ToString("X")[0]));
            output.Add(Convert.ToByte(first.ToString("X")[0]));
        }
    }

    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(output.ToArray());
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up uncovering two issues in this code. One of which was causing the issue described.

The first issue, which did not cause any blatant issues, was the "Content-Type" header not specifying UTF-8 character encoding. This appears to be minor and no obvious problems were caused by it.

The new header values are as follows:

```
NameValueCollection head = new NameValueCollection
                       {
                           {"Authorization", oauth.GetHttpHeader(method, target, null, data)},
                           {"Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8"},
                           {"User-Agent", "AgentX"}
                       };
```

The more significant issue was that `WebClient` was being allowed to percent encode the body of the message using the default percent encoding rather than `RFC 3986`. By changing from `WebClient.UploadValues()` to `WebClient.UploadData()` and manually creating the bytes to send, the issues we were seeing were resolved.